# How to add tooltip pointer to div using CSS

Tags: css

**An update:** I see that my question is more of CSS and not Reactjs. so I have updated the code with HTML and CSS.

**Illustrations:**

The code below is working fine when a user clicks. Now all I want to add is the tooltip pointer using CSS. The pointer should be
pointing towards the show button.

How can I achieve it using CSS?

See sample of what I want to achieve. The screenshot with arrow pointing towards it.

[image: screenshot showing tooltip pointer as indicated bty arrow]

**Here is the full code**

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

#stuffToShow {
    display:none;
}

#checkbox {
    opacity:0.01;

}

#checkbox:checked + #stuffToShow {
    display:block;
}

.checkbox_tooltip {
position: relative;
boxShadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
borderRadius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
border: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.4);
width: 500px;
height: 200px;
float: right;
}

</style>

<body>
<label style="float:right;" for="checkbox" id="checkboxLabel">Show Content via Tooltip</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />


<div id="stuffToShow" class="checkbox_tooltip">
    content appears here
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using `border-width`

```
  .Tooltip:before,
  .Tooltip:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
  }
 .Tooltip:before {
   border-left: 10px solid transparent;
   border-right: 10px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 10px solid #ccc;
   top: -10px;
   right: 15px;
  }
 .Tooltip:after {
   border-left: 8px solid transparent;
   border-right: 8px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 8px solid #f7f7f7;
   top: -8px;
   right: 17px;
 }
```

Grab working demo code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/k9y3354j73)

Comment: Thanks Sir Sivadass